# Какой уровень транзакции у функций PL/pgSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Из [документации Постгерса](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/10/plpgsql-porting#:%7E:text=%D0%92%20%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%20PL%2FpgSQL,%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82%20%D1%81%D0%BD%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B8.): "В функции на PL/pgSQL нельзя использовать COMMIT. Функция работает в рамках некоторой внешней транзакции, и поэтому COMMIT будет означать прекращение выполнения функции."

Пользуясь гуглом и методом научного тыка, я понял, что код, исполняемый функцией в Постгресе атомарен. Явно объявить в нём транзакцию мы также не можем, получаем ошибку.

Подскажите, пожалуйста:

1. Если можно в деталях, как вообще работает транзакционность в функциях PL/pgSQL?
2. Конкретно интересующий меня вопрос: какой уровень изоляции у этих неявных "внешних" транзакций? Интересует, в первую очередь, с точки зрения видимости изменений из параллельных транзакций и блокировок, накладываемых на строки (если Постгрес так делает, с концепцией MVCC знаком поверхностно).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Так же как и любой запрос:

- если запрос пришёл при уже открытой внешней транзакции - работает в этой транзакции с теми параметрами транзакции, с которыми та открыта
- если явной транзакции не открыто, то открываем неявно транзакцию перед началом обработки запроса и после окончания запроса эту транзакцию коммитим.

Ну а чтобы вызвать функцию, вам нужно прислать запрос. Таким образом, вызов функции всегда находится внутри внешней транзакции, открытой явно либо же неявно.

Уровень изоляции, если не был запрошен явно при открытии транзакции, используется указанный в настройке `default_transaction_isolation` (обычно read committed). Всё поведение в транзакции по блокировкам, видимости MVCC снимка данных - по обычным правилам. Из специфики PL/pgSQL разве что можно упомянуть неявные [savepoint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-savepoint.html)'ы
при использовании `EXCEPTION` блоков, что довольно-таки не бесплатно.

Comment: Правильно понимаю, что под "чтобы вызвать функцию, вам нужно прислать запрос" - имеется ввиду любой вызов, а не запрос из внешней системы? условно, select * from my_function также попадает под Ваше определение?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. То, чем вы подключитесь к postgresql и потом будете присылать запросы - *всегда* внешняя система. Будь то psql, какой-то gui разработчика, собственное приложение, стороннее готовое приложение, да хоть даже telnet (если вы умеете писать в нём бинарный протокол) - это всё клиенты и они всегда внешние по отношению к СУБД.

Comment: Никогда не задумывался о том, что обращение из IDE есть "внешние запрос" к ядру СУБД, хоть это и предельно логично. Понял, спасибо!